# NextJS MDX files not being collected in AWS but working locally

Tags: next.js, mdx

Packages:

```
    "@next/mdx": "^14.0.4",
    "next": "13.5.6",
```

docker

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:20-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY postcss.config.js .

COPY public public/
COPY src src/

RUN npm install

ENV NODE_ENV production


RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

The old [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30719) was closed without resolution and seems to be ignored with 'works sometimes', but is not working on AWS docker pipeline and is i don't know what the difference is between their config and my machine.

next.config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')()

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    instrumentationHook: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
  },
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
}

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the dockerfile is copying the correct files on the process.

After adding mdx files there was a change in configuration to nextjs and it seems that file is not being copied to the WORKDIR

```
COPY next.config.js .
```